# C# Order List of Strings by value

Tags: c#, list

I have a List:

```
List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
```

It may contain values like this:

> -3,003-m
>
> 2,086
>
> -1, 006-mx
>
> etc.

I sorted it with this:

```
allValues = allValues.OrderBy(q => q).ToList<string>();
allValues.Reverse();
```

The problem is, that it somehow does not differ between normal values and negative ones (I'd expect that to work even if they are strings).

So instead of:

> 3,001 | 3,003-m | 2,086 | 2,145-m | 1,004 | 0,033 | -1,008-m | -2,490

it looks like this:

> 3,001 | 3,003-m | 2,086 | -2,490 | 2,145-m | -1,008-m | 1,004 |  0,033

If now negative or positive, it seems to treat them as the same, resulting in a somewhat random sorted List.

I am aware that there might be better approaches to this, but I wanted to know if it is possible to resolve this in this specific scenario.

Comment: You want 3.001, 3.003-m then 2.086 ? what's the logic ?

Comment: what is `-m` or `-mx`?

Comment: @Thomas It should sort by the first number, shouldn't it?

Comment: String ordering and int/decimal ordering are two different things.

Comment: @HimBromBeere An abbreviation for something, but that's not important. only the number before the comma matters, the rest can be in a random order. (e.g. 3,006-mx | 3,085 | 3,143 can be 3,085 | 3,006-mx | 3,143 as well, it doesn't matter)

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks sherlock. But string ordering should still have a consistent rule, shouldn't it? I don't understand why "-" is treated as if it does not exist.

Comment: Do you want the result to be greater to smaller? then shouldn't the expected result be: 3,003-m | 3,001 | 2,145-m | 2,086 | 1,004 | 0,033 | -1,008-m | -2,490 ?

Comment: @Ian Yeah it should, but that doesn't work. HimBromBeere 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990070/c-sharp-order-list-of-strings-by-value/34990166#34990166) provided me with the correct solution. Thank you, nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `allValues` is a list of strings also the rules for sorting strings apply for sorting. As you need numerical rules of sorting you have to convert the elements to numbers before sorting, e.g. by calling `Convert.ToInt32`).

So your ordering looks like this:

```
var result = allValues.OrderBy(q => 
    Convert.ToInt32(q.SubString(0, q.IndexOf(","))))
    .ToList<string>();
```

Which will perform on only extracting the numeric part and order by it, however it retains the actual strings.

Comment: This is a comment ... Calling Convert.ToInt32 on  -1,008-m will throw an exception.

Comment: The problem is the -m / -mx part. I need them in my values, but because of that, I can't convert them to int.

Comment: I don't know if someone ever told you this, but you're a genius. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
var result = (from s in allValues
             let val = s.Split(new string[] { "-m" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
             let val2 = double.Parse(val)
             orderby val2
             select s).Reverse();
```

The idea is to get the first element divided by `"-m"`, you can simply add the split option with something else (`"-mx", "-p"`, etc) as per necessary.

Comment: There is string -mx too in the example, I will suppose there will be more from this.

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple possible endings (like -mx or -d), but nonetheless thank you for this idea.

Comment: @Ian I didn't say it didn't work. It does indeed work.^^